# Add custom string attribute in my custom android View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a cusom view derived from TableLayout, and I need to declare String property Title, like this:

```
<com.mycompany.controls.NavigationControllerView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.usetech.com/apk/res/onroad"
title="@string/nav_title"
...
/>
```

(to be able specify value via resource reference).
I've specified this property in values/attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="NavigationControllerView">
    <attr name="title" format="string"/>
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

In my code I'm trying:

```
public class NavigationControllerView extends TableLayout {
public NavigationControllerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.inc_header, this);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NavigationControllerView);
    CharSequence title = a.getString(R.styleable.NavigationControllerView_title);
    if (title != null)
        setTitle(title.toString());
}
...
```

but no luck, title is always null. Do you see where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
<com.mycompany.controls.NavigationControllerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/onroad" 
    app:title="@string/nav_title" 
... />
```

do not miss app: prefix.
Also correct namespace uri should be used.

Comment: Ups, you are right, but even using app prefix Title is null, neither specifying resource reference neither providing direct string value

Comment: maybe you're using whong custom namespace? I use xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/'packagepath'" where 'packagepath' - root package path

Comment: Right! Thank you, schema really should be in form: http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mycompany.myapp
Please fix xmlns:app in your answer and I'll mark it as correct